# Remove and replace multiple commas in string

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have this dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':{0: 'John,Smith', 1: 'Peter,Blue', 2:'Larry,One,Stacy,Orange' , 3:'Joe,Good' , 4:'Pete,High,Anne,Green'}})
```

yielding:

```
name
0   John,Smith
1   Peter,Blue
2   Larry,One,Stacy,Orange
3   Joe,Good
4   Pete,High,Anne,Green
```

I would like to:

- remove commas (replace them by one space)
- wherever I have 2 persons in one cell, insert the "&"symbol after the first person family name and before the second person name.

Desired output:

```
name
0   John Smith
1   Peter Blue
2   Larry One & Stacy Orange
3   Joe Good
4   Pete High & Anne Green
```

Tried this code below, but it simply removes commas. I could not find how to insert the "&"symbol in the same code.

```
df['name']= df['name'].str.replace(r',', '', regex=True)
```

Disclaimer : all names in this table are fictitious. No identification with actual persons (living or deceased)is intended or should be inferred.

Comment: Can you have 3 persons or more in a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':{0: 'John,Smith', 1: 'Peter,Blue', 2:'Larry,One,Stacy,Orange' , 3:'Joe,Good' , 4:'Pete,High,Anne,Green'}})
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(',',' ').str.replace(r'(\w+ \w+) ', r'\1 & ', regex=True)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
                       name
0                John Smith
1                Peter Blue
2  Larry One & Stacy Orange
3                  Joe Good
4    Pete High & Anne Green
```

Explanation: replace `,`s using spaces, then use replace again to change one-or-more word characters followed by space followed by one-or-more word character followed by space using content of capturing group (which includes everything but last space) followed by space followed by `&` character followed by space.

Answer (score 3):

With single regex replacement:

```
df['name'].str.replace(r',([^,]+)(,)?', lambda m:f" {m.group(1)}{' & ' if m.group(2) else ''}")
```

---

```
0                  John Smith
1                  Peter Blue
2    Larry One & Stacy Orange
3                    Joe Good
4      Pete High & Anne Green
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import re

def separate_names(original_str):
    spaces = re.sub(r',([^,]*(?:,|$))', r' \1', original_str)
    return spaces.replace(',', ' & ')

df['spaced'] = df.name.map(separate_names)
df
```

I created a function called separate_names which replaces the odd number of commas with spaces using regex. The remaining commas (even) are then replaced by & using the replace function. Finally I used the map function to apply separate_names to each row. The output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In `replace` statement you should replace comma with space. Please put *space* between '' -> so you have ' '

```
df['name']= df['name'].str.replace(r',', ' ', regex=True)
                           inserted space ^ here
```

Comment: hi, how does this handle the insertion of &

Comment: and to clarify, not my downvote...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).